# How to return an object value in a list that has a certain dictionary value

Tags: c#, dictionary

Say I have an object:

```
public class Person
{
   public IDictionary<string, string> RoleTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Where the roletypes have a name as a key and a description as a value:

- Manager: The manager who does stuff
- CIO: Who knows what they do
- CEO:    No one knows what they do.

So now I have say a list of People:

IEnumerable people;

I want to somehow get back from that list the person who is the CEO:

```
people.Single(x => x.RoleTypes.Contains("CEO"));
```

Well that doesn't even compile.

Anyone know how to get it to work?

Comment: "doesn't even compile." --- and I'm sure it returns back useful message. Why to avoid reading it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check the keys (if the title is the key of the dictionary):

```
people.Single(x => x.RoleTypes.ContainsKey("CEO"));
```

That being said, this data organizational structure is odd - it would make more sense to keep the titles and descriptions separate, so they aren't duplicated within each person.  The user could maintain just a list of their titles, and the desciption of that title could be looked up elsewhere.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `x.RoleTypes.ContainsKey("CEO")` or will the LINQ `x.RoleTypes.Keys.Contains` extension method still have the O(1) lookup time that `ContainsKey` does?

Comment: Did a quick LINQPad test, hardly benchmark sound, but seems that both take about the same amount of time, so I guess it still goes through the same hash lookup process rather than enumerating each entry.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I edited because I like your option better, even if perf is equal.

Answer (score 1):

Does TryGetValue(key) not do it?